# How to upload video from google drive to youtube channel without api?

Tags: google-apps-script, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

I want to transfer my videos from google drive to youtube but i have some problems:

1. I have no any access to Google Console for enabling youtube api v3.
2. Due to some limitations, I can only use Google Colab and Google Apps Script. I can't buy VPS for some reasons.
3. I can enable youtube api v3 from google apps script libraries only, but it have quota 10,000 units a day limition. That's why I have to use selenium.

**Now i want to know:**

1. Can i install selenium webdriver in google apps script?
2. Can i mount google drive as virtual storage to google apps script?
3. Can i use selenium webdriver for this transfer in google colab without enabling youtube api v3?

**I want to mount my google drive as storage to google apps script or google colab and then upload video to youtube by selenium webdriver without youtube api v3 because i have no any access to Google Console for enabling that api.**

Comment: Use an html input type="file".  If you have multiple question ask them separately.  large video files will be a problem no matter how you do it.

Comment: @Cooper I sniffed [https://upload.youtube.com](https://upload.youtube.com) in my windows environment and realized that when i select video file from virtual drive that created by google drive desktop version for uploading to youtube, [https://upload.youtube.com](https://upload.youtube.com) has no any limition about file size or quota! in sniffed packet used some values like `&upload_protocol=resumable&origin=`, maybe file size or quota limitions applied only on youtube api v3 and [https://upload.youtube.com](https://upload.youtube.com) has no any limition!